# Select the values BETWEEN [array] AND [array]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I need to get some values from a table by using ranges.

Example:
I need to get all the values where 'values' is BETWEEN 4 AND 10.

```
Result.where('values BETWEEN ? AND ?', 4, 10)
```

I also need to get all the values where 'values' is BETWEEN 11 AND 20.

```
Result.where('values BETWEEN ? AND ?', 11, 20)
```

Is it possible to get this with one query?

Comment: You can `UNNEST` the arrays and `JOIN` this unnested table to filter your results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Result.where('values BETWEEN ? AND ? OR values BETWEEN ? AND ?', 4, 10, 11, 20)
```

or even shorter **if all your values are integers** (since `BETWEEN` in Postgresql is inclusive on both ends):

```
Result.where('values BETWEEN ? AND ?', 4, 20)
```